# Is there any way to access layers in tensorflow_hub.KerasLayer object?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to use a pre-trained model from tensorflow hub into my object detection model. I wrapped a model from hub as a KerasLayer object following the official instruction. Then I realized that **I cannot access the layers in this pre-trained model**. But I need to use outputs from some specific layers to build my model. Is there any way to access layers in tensorflow_hub.KerasLayer object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one to be able to do that easily, the creator of the pretrained model would have needed to make that output ready to be accessed. E.g. by having an extra function or an extra signature that outputs the activation you want to use.

Comment: So it will be impossible if the creator does not provide it?

Answer (score 4):

There is an undocumented way to get intermediate layers out of some TF2 SavedModels exported from TF-Slim, such as https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v1/feature_vector/4: passing `return_endpoints=True` to the SavedModel's `__call__` function changes the output to a `dict`.

NOTE: This interface is subject to change or removal, and has known issues.

```py
model = tfhub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v1/feature_vector/4', trainable=False, arguments=dict(return_endpoints=True))
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((224, 224, 3))
outputs = model(input)
for k, v in sorted(outputs.items()):
  print(k, v.shape)
```

Output for this example:

```
InceptionV1/Conv2d_1a_7x7 (None, 112, 112, 64)
InceptionV1/Conv2d_2b_1x1 (None, 56, 56, 64)
InceptionV1/Conv2d_2c_3x3 (None, 56, 56, 192)
InceptionV1/MaxPool_2a_3x3 (None, 56, 56, 64)
InceptionV1/MaxPool_3a_3x3 (None, 28, 28, 192)
InceptionV1/MaxPool_4a_3x3 (None, 14, 14, 480)
InceptionV1/MaxPool_5a_2x2 (None, 7, 7, 832)
InceptionV1/Mixed_3b (None, 28, 28, 256)
InceptionV1/Mixed_3c (None, 28, 28, 480)
InceptionV1/Mixed_4b (None, 14, 14, 512)
InceptionV1/Mixed_4c (None, 14, 14, 512)
InceptionV1/Mixed_4d (None, 14, 14, 512)
InceptionV1/Mixed_4e (None, 14, 14, 528)
InceptionV1/Mixed_4f (None, 14, 14, 832)
InceptionV1/Mixed_5b (None, 7, 7, 832)
InceptionV1/Mixed_5c (None, 7, 7, 1024)
InceptionV1/global_pool (None, 1, 1, 1024)
default (None, 1024)
```

Issues to be aware of:

- Undocumented, subject to change or removal, not available consistently.
- `__call__` computes all outputs (and applies all update ops during training) irrespective of the ones being used later on.

Source: [https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/453](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/453#issuecomment-571986326)

Comment: Thx! An interesting way to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Since `return_endpoints=True` doesn't seem to work anymore.

You can do this :

```py
efficientnet_lite0_base_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/lite0/feature-vector/2",
    output_shape=[1280],
    trainable=False
)

print("Thickness of the model:", len(efficientnet_lite0_base_layer.weights))
print ("{:<80} {:<20} {:<10}".format('Layer','Shape','Type'))

for i in range(len(efficientnet_lite0_base_layer.weights)):
    model_weights_raw_string = str(efficientnet_lite0_base_layer.weights[i])
    model_weights_wo_weights = model_weights_raw_string.split(", numpy", 1)[0]
    dtype = model_weights_wo_weights.split(" dtype=")[1]
    shape = model_weights_wo_weights.split(" shape=")[1].split(" dtype=")[0]
    
    print ("{:<80} {:<20} {:<10}".format(efficientnet_lite0_base_layer.weights[i].name, shape, dtype))
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't give you programmatic access to the layers, but it does allow you to inspect them.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

resnet_v2 = hub.load(os.path.join(tfhub_dir, 'imagenet_resnet_v2_50_classification_5'))

print(tf.__version__)
resnet_v2.summary()
single_keras_layer = resnet_v2.layers[0]
variables = single_keras_layer.variables

for i, v in enumerate(variables):
    print('[{:03d}] {} [{}]'.format(i, v.name, v.shape))
```

Output

```
2.13.0
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 keras_layer_6 (KerasLayer)  (None, 1001)              25615849  
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 25615849 (97.72 MB)
Trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 25615849 (97.72 MB)
_________________________________________________________________
[000] resnet_v2_50/block2/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/shortcut/biases:0 [(512,)]
[001] resnet_v2_50/block2/unit_4/bottleneck_v2/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma:0 [(128,)]
[002] resnet_v2_50/block3/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/conv2/weights:0 [(3, 3, 256, 256)]
[003] resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/conv3/biases:0 [(2048,)]
[004] resnet_v2_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/shortcut/biases:0 [(256,)]
[005] resnet_v2_50/block3/unit_2/bottleneck_v2/preact/gamma:0 [(1024,)]
[006] resnet_v2_50/block3/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma:0 [(256,)]
[007] resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma:0 [(512,)]
[008] resnet_v2_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/preact/gamma:0 [(64,)]
[009] resnet_v2_50/block1/unit_2/bottleneck_v2/conv3/weights:0 [(1, 1, 64, 256)]
[010] resnet_v2_50/block2/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/preact/gamma:0 [(256,)]
[011] resnet_v2_50/block2/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/conv2/BatchNorm/gamma:0 [(128,)]
[012] resnet_v2_50/block2/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/conv3/biases:0 [(512,)]
...
[268] resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/preact/moving_variance:0 [(1024,)]
[269] resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v2/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0 [(512,)]
[270] resnet_v2_50/block2/unit_2/bottleneck_v2/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0 [(128,)]
[271] resnet_v2_50/block1/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/preact/moving_mean:0 [(256,)]
```