# How to see the modify layers in models from tensorflow_hub

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a GAN following steps on
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf_hub_generative_image_module.

It uses `tensorflow_hub.load` to load a pre train model.

`progan = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/progan-128/1").signatures['default']`

The type of progan is a function.

````
print(type(progan))
>>> <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction'>```
````

```
for i in progan.__dict__:
  print(i)
>>> _variable_holder
_signature
_arg_keywords
_num_positional_args
_func_graph
_captured_inputs
_captured_closures
_function_spec
_pre_initialized_function_spec
_output_shapes
_attrs
_garbage_collector
_delayed_rewrite_functions
_first_order_tape_functions
_higher_order_tape_functions
_inference_function
```

What should I do if I want to get the model and add or remove some layers?

Comment: I think you can't or won't be easy because Hub models are treated as black-boxes and should be used with proper input.

Comment: you can use an input and print the output of the hub model to see the layers in use. you can also use it along tf.keras.Sequential to create custom model for transfer learning .   Attaching relevant thread for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996588/is-there-any-way-to-access-layers-in-tensorflow-hub-keraslayer-object                              https://sennalabs.com/en/blogs/deep-learning-development-with-Google-Colab